# What is the computational power required for training High resolution (4024 x 3036) images using VGG16-Net?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am working on a classification of high-resolution images using VGG16-Net in keras.
But I am unable to use images of size beyond (600 x 600) resolution for training using Batch size 1 on nVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 GPU,
I am facing Resource Exhaustion error OOM i.e unable to allocate tensor of the shape [18, 64, 600, 600].
Can anyone please suggest me any solution for this? 
I want to use the large size images since I am labeling the images as Good and Bad based on the very small difference.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This doesn't look like a batch size of `1` to me. I haven't used VGG-16 in keras, but it looks to me that your error comes from a layer with `64` feature maps, and `18` batches.

Comment: Hi @Ash , thank you for reply, but I specifically given batch size = 1 in model.fit while training VGG on 600 x 600 resolution image.

Answer (score 0):

The whole network plus batch data need to be able to fit into VRAM. If you really do need to use high resolution images then you need to use a smaller network.
vgg-16 is old and inefficient anyway, not recommended for a new project. You could lookup things like mobilenetv2 or mnasnet but bare in mind that all of these commonly used models are generally optimized for around 600x600 or much smaller. Out of interest, I have tried training CNNs on very high resolution images, just to see what would happen and I found that of course, they train and run painfully slowly with much reduced accuracy - if all of the features in the images are very large with respect to the convolutional filters, then the filters won't be able to pick up on them.